# Remove comment blocks bounded by `#|...|#` in textfile - python

Tags: python, regex, string, comments, text-files

How could I remove commented blocks from a text files, the comments are encased within `#|` and `|#\n`?

**Infile:**

```
#|\n this is some sort of foo bar\n that I don't care about|#\nthen there is a foo bar sentence that I want but i don't want that foo bar in within the hex pipe pipe hex comment block.#| and even so, i don't want this section to appear|#\n with some crazy sentence...
```

**Desired output:**

```
then there is a foo bar sentence that I want but i don't want that foo bar in within the hex pipe pipe hex comment block. with some crazy sentence...
```

Is there a better way to remove the comment blocks other than the following?

```
txt = '''#|\n this is some sort of foo bar\n that I don't care about|#\nthen there is a foo bar sentence that I want but i don't want that foo bar in within the hex pipe pipe hex comment block.#| and even so, i don't want this section to appear|#\n with some crazy sentence...'''

pointer = 0
while pointer < len(txt):
    try:
        start = txt.index('#|',pointer)
        end = txt.index('|#\n',start)
        cleantxt+=txt[pointer:start]
        pointer = end+3
    except ValueError:
        cleantxt+=txt[pointer:]
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = '''#|\n this is some sort of foo bar\n that I don't care about|#\nthen there is a foo bar sentence that I want but i don't want that foo bar in within the hex pipe pipe hex comment block.#| and even so, i don't want this section to appear|#\n with some crazy sentence...'''
>>> txt2 = re.sub(r'#\|.*?\|#', '', txt, flags=re.DOTALL)  # remove multiline comment
>>> txt2
"\nthen there is a foo bar sentence that I want but i don't want that foo bar in within the hex pipe pipe hex comment block.\n with some crazy sentence..."
```

You may also `strip()` the result to remove unwanted line breaks.